# detect original web site URL in PHP using JS from external server

Tags: javascript, php, webserver

Let's say we have two web sites `https://aa.tld` (WS_A) and `https://bb.tld` (WS_B).
And let's say we have a third server `https://ss.tld` (SS), where some scripts like a small javascript framework are hosted. This small framework provides e.g. spam free email form or sms service to website admin or so.

This JS framework is embedded in WS_A und WS_B with a regular JS link like `<script src="https://ss.tld/w/widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

On server side (SS) this is translated using htaccess to widget.php, where widget.php acts like and outputs JS using PHP header `header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8');`

My question is: Is it possible to use PHP on this SS-script to detect the original web site URL like `https://aa.tld` or `https://bb.tld` ?

The purpose is I want the script to provide e.g. only email form to WS_A and both email and sms to WS_B. And I don't want to use a JS switch using `window.location.href` because user could be able to digg into `https://ss.tld/w/widget.js` and gets information about other web sites using this script, and possibly may compromise the script using browser like MozFF admin tools.

Appreciate your ideas, thanks.

**UPDATE regarding answers below to share my experiences**

Now I am happy with it.

On Website WS_A: `<script src="https://ss.tld/w/856z6gg4" type="text/javascript" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

In HTACCESS: `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/+]+)$ js.php?key=$1 [L]`

Here the SS php script (experimental, working):

```
<?php
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8');
    
function servername($url) {
    $res = parse_url($url);
    return $res['host'];
}

$keys = array(
    '856z6gg4'=>'aa.tld'
);

$origin = filter_var ( $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$referer = filter_var ( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$key = filter_var ( $_GET['key'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$fromarray = $keys[$key];

if (array_key_exists($key, $keys)) {
    if (isset ($referer) && $referer != '' && $fromarray == servername($referer) && $fromarray == servername($origin)) {
        echo 'document.writeln ("domain ' . $referer . ' is checked with HTTP_REFERER.<br />");';
    }
    else if ($fromarray == servername($origin)) {
        echo 'document.writeln ("domain ' . $origin . ' is checked with HTTP_ORIGIN.<br />");';
    } else echo 'document.writeln ("domain not allowed.<br />");';
} else echo 'document.writeln ("domain not allowed.<br />");';
    
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Use a GET parameter when embedding the script, that you can evaluate on the server side? `src="https://ss.tld/w/widget.js?forSite=WS_A"` or something like that.

Comment: @CBroe Yeah, I know this is possible. But I did not mentioned it, because this is not what I want. Thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: Okay, we can not guess that, so stuff like this should be mentioned in your question right away. The referrer is massively unreliable, IMHO it does not make sense to even try and use that. Maybe you could have the other sites embed your script with the `crossorigin` attribute set, and then check the `Origin` header on the receiving end? (That is not supported in IE, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#browser_compatibility - but that’s pretty much a dead browser anyway.)

Comment: @CBroe Thanks again for the crossorigin hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` but there are browsers that don't send this.

I advise you to put a parameter
in serverA and B
ex:
in serverA

```
<script src="https://ss.tld/w/widget.js?host=A" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in serverB

```
<script src="https://ss.tld/w/widget.js?host=B" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this short and clear answer. I guess I will mix the proposal in your answer and yours and CBro's answer. Will use both, `HTTP_REFERER` and `GET` parameter, and check whether `HTTP_REFERER` is available or not (preferred) otherwise use `GET` (fallback)